# Documentation update for Google Client .NET API?

Tags: google-api-dotnet-client

Google's documentation is out of sync with the most recent GA version of the API.

For instance, in all their examples for working with the API, it is mentioned to use the Fetch() method, whereas it has been renamed to Execute().

For example, for [Parents: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/parents/get) we are told to:

```
 public static bool IsFileInFolder(DriveService service, String folderId, String fileId) {
try {
  service.Parents.Get(fileId, folderId).Fetch();
} catch (GoogleApiRequestException e) {
...
```

Apparently this [breaking change](http://google-api-dotnet-client.blogspot.com/2013/06/announcing-release-of-140-beta_26.html) was made in June '13.

Perhaps this is not a problem for established users of the .NET API, but for novices it could take a while to figure out that the error they're getting is because of renamed methods. So are there plans to update the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

You are right.

That doc-set is out of sync. Thanks for mentioning that!

Anyway please take a look in the library documentation - https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/ and its samples https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse?repo=samples (There is also a Drive sample there).